# SQL Server CE 3.5 compatibility

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a C# .Net 3.5 application using SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 as the database.

I can xcopy deploy and run the application on a laptop running Windows Vista.

However, if I copy the same set of files onto a machine running Windows 7 or 8, I get a `Target of Invocation...` error.

Does anyone know if SQL Server CE 3.5 is compatible with Windows 7 or 8?

If not, is SQL Server CE 4.0? (And if I do need SQL Server CE 4.0 will I still be able to use .net 3.5?)

Is there a chart somewhere that says what versions of SQL Server CE are compatible/required for the different operating systems?

Many thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 and 4.0 are compatible with Windows 7 and 8.
I have a chart here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2010/11/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html

I sounds like you are facing issues with x86 vs AMD64 platforms, do you include both set of dll files? And of course, all included SQL Server Compact files must have exact same file version.

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for your response.  I did not realize there were two sets of dlls (I've not done much work with SQL CE.)  Do I just include both sets of DLLs in the application directory?  Do I need to do anything in Visual studio so that both sets are recognized?

Comment: Read the linked articles in the blog post mentioned in my reply

Comment: Hello ErikEJ: Thank you for your reply.  I apologise for the delayed response but to be honest, I lost myself in your amazing blogspot site.  There is a ton of info there - thank you for assembling that!

Comment: Question:  I got the application working on the target machine (Win7, Processor_Architecture:AMD64).  But only by following the steps in an article that suggested using an x86 build configuration.  (Can’t find the article now but I remember you actually posted a comment to the article saying you can deploy both sets of dlls.)  My preference is to not have to use a separate build configuration so I’d really like to get the application working using the steps you listed in your "private deployment" article.I’m not using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework so I didn’t do all the config file mods.

Comment: When I run the application I get the “Exception has been thrown by target of an invocation” error with an inner exception of “Unable to Load DLL ‘sqlceme35.dll’: The specified module could not be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)”  Can you think of anything else I should try?  One thing I am confused is how the application knows to use one set of DLLs over the other.  Does the “Processor_Architecture” environment variable influence the behavior of the application somehow?

Comment: Just follow the instructions here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html

Comment: Hi Erik.  That is the article I was referring to in my previous comment.  I've followed those steps exactly.  Do you happen to know if there is a working test .net 3.5 solution I can download anywhere?

Comment: I have emailed you.  Thanks!

Comment: For those who come here with the same issue: The problem turned out to be that I was using the wrong version of 64bit DLLs.  I had the SP2 32bit dlls, but the 64bit dlls were not the SP2 ones.  Verify this by right-clicking on the dll, selecting /properties/details tab.  Note the version. The files in my AMD64 folder were older (3.5.5692.0), not 3.5 SP2 = 3.5.8080.0.  THANKS SO MUCH to ErikEJ for finding this.